# Lift HTTP routing

Tags: lift

Is it possible in lift to use routing files? I want be able to deploy my app with different configs (locales). Sample: I have two domains "mydomain.com" and "mydomain.pl" that run te same app. I want the .pl site to have different urls as the .com one. (mydomain.com/imprint and mydomain.pl/somethingelse, both are routing to one file inside the code).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

1. Use a reverse proxy on front of Lift to deal the rewriting paths and aliases (nginx or Apache HTTP Server will do the trick).
2. Add this to the Lift Boot.scala:

```
    LiftRules.statelessRewrite.prepend(NamedPF("PublicJobsRedirect") { 
        case RewriteRequest(
            ParsePath("somethingelse" :: Nil, _, _, _), _, _) =>
                RewriteResponse("imprint" :: Nil)
    })
```

3. Use internal Lift response cycle:

```
    val sampleTemplate = Templates("imprint" :: Nil)
    def sampleResponse : Box[LiftResponse] =
    for {
        req 
                session.processTemplate(sampleTemplate, req, req.path, 200)
            case _ =>
                Empty
            }      
        }
    } yield {
        response
    }

    LiftRules.responseTransformers.append {
        case resp if resp.toResponse.code == 404 => sampleResponse openOr resp
        case resp => resp
    }
```

NOTE: The first option leads you to a whole mess of external rules to your application and is cheap and easy to do it at the begining but get horrible with more and more cases to maintain. The second options is pretty cool but exposes the redirect path to the user, so that leads us to the thrid option, more complex in sintax but it does not expose the new url to the user, the url is kept internal to Lift. There are sometimes that you do want to expose the new url and sometimes you want to hide it, so those are options up to you.